# How to set the scheme tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

The part of a URL before the : is called the "scheme". Examples include "http", "https", "ftp", as well as "file".

The scheme tells the browser "what to do" with the rest of the URL, different schemes can have different formats after the :.

All I need to know is what config file to edit and the syntax to use. I need to allow Tomcat to serve local file request:

```
<a href="file://///server/Attachments/area/17-00123/">Case Folder</a>
```

This was working before we upgraded Tomcat, so I know it is possable.

This is what I have found so far.

[Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference - See Scheme Section](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 0):

The usual place to configure such things in Tomcat is `<tomcat>/conf/server.xml` with a `<Connector>` element. Here is a quote from a default server.xml:

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Having said that, I will point out that I have never seen a configuration for a "file" connector.

I have seen Tomcat configured to serve static files over http or https. For more detail, see [this page](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/):

> Tomcat can be configured to read files from anywhere on disk and serve
>   them on a specific URL. This configuration is completely separate to
>   your application config – you could, if you wanted, just start Tomcat
>   and have it serve static files from disk with no webapps running. The
>   configuration is in Tomcat’s server.xml configuration file and looks
>   like this (the bit that needs to be added is in red):
>
> ```
>      <Host appBase="webapps"
>        autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
>        xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
> ...
>        <Context docBase="/home/stuff" path="/static" />
> ```
>
> A  element is added inside the  element.
>   Context has two attributes: docBase is the directory on disk that
>   contains your static files and path is the URL that you want to serve
>   the files on.

Comment: Thanks, we had made this change before I asked this question. The issue with this solution is that we loose AD NTFS security. The account tomcat is running on needs access to the folder. This makes all the files in that folder accessible to everyone who has access to the URL. We need then to have access according to the NTFS permissions.